# Intercepting requests made by WebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, http, request, browser

Is it possible to intercept all requests made by a `WebBrowser` control?

I want to modify the request URI of every single request (including requests for images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an event called "[BeforeNavigate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326(VS.85).aspx)" that is called before any request is made.  You can use this to modify the outgoing requests.

Comment: Is it called before any request, or before each page change? By request I mean the individual requests for images, css, etc.

Comment: No, it's only called for navigations. There's no public way to monitor individual subdownloads. You can use Fiddler for that.