# Capture http data using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm writing an app with the WebBrowser control and wanted to know how to retrieve the http traffic via the WebBrowser control.  post, gets, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811587/intercepting-requests-made-by-webbrowser-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebClient class or the underlying WebRequest based classes if you need to programmically make requests.

If you are interested in monitoring it for debug purposes then get [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) which is a free HTTP debugging proxy.

Comment: The control is embedded in my application.  I use it to allow the user to visually navigate the website and I want to be able to capture the http data and perform analysis on the information.

Comment: Then fiddler is the tool you need.  You can configure the proxy settings of the application in the System.Net section of the applications .config file.

Comment: Fiddler is an another application.  I would need fiddler like capability in my application itself.