# How to intercept http request in C#?

Tags: c#, http, webview, uwp

I'm trying to develop an C# UWP application. Its view contains webview control and html contents are all contained in this solution.
I want to intercept http request and if it is GET request, return something like json, text, or others.
I could do this when I developed an android application. Android supplies some methods "shouldInterceptRequest" and types like "WebRequestResponse".
Can I do this in C#(not Xamarin)? And if it is yes, please tell me how to do.
Sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

not about WebBrowser, but about WebView.

Comment: You want to act as a web server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting requests made by WebBrowser in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811587/intercepting-requests-made-by-webbrowser-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No. I want to catch request and return response without web server.

Comment: So you want to load the HTML (that is embedded in your solution) file to your WebView?

Comment: yes. i want to load html embedded in my solution to my webview

Answer (score 0):

Edit

You can listen to [NavigationStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigationStarting) event

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyWebView.NavigationStarting += MyWebViewOnNavigationStarting;
}

private void MyWebViewOnNavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    string navigatingUri = args.Uri.ToString();

}
```

**Note** that this only capture navigation event inside the webview.

Original "wrong" answer

1. Place your HTML file in `Asset` Folder
2. In your web view, put the `Source` with `ms-appx-web:///Assets/{htmlFileName}`

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Foo.html"></WebView>
```

Or via code

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/Foo.html"));
}
```

Comment: I already can display my htmls using WebView.Navigate(). I want to intercept http request(when a tag clicked, button clicked,  and the others)